# How Do I Modify My Linear Gradient Width to 100%?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer, linear-gradients

I have a linear gradient with red at the top going to white at the bottom in my footer CSS. I want the gradient to be the width of the display without black margins to the left and right. I have similar code in my header markup for a solid red line that does not have black margins.

CSS

```
body { font-family: Arial; background-color: $black; width: 100%; font-size: 18px; margin:0 auto; }
footer, header { font-family: Eurostile; padding-top: 15px; margin:0 auto; .row { .row-col-img-padding { [class*="col-"] { padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; } } } }
footer {
    color: $gray; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 90%; line-height: 100%; a { color: $bluedark; } 
    background: red; 
    background: linear-gradient($red, $white);
    background: -khtml-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
}
header { background-color: $black; p { color: $grayLight; font-weight: bold; font-size: 100%; line-height: 100%; } }
```

CSS for solid line in header where the red line fills up the screen with no margins.

```
#back-red { background-color: $red; padding-bottom: 15px; }
```

Markup

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="row row-col-img-padding">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-facebook-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "Facebook"), "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-twitter-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "Twitter"), "https://twitter.com/xxxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "LinkedIn"), "http://www.linkedin.com/company/xxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-bernard-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :translation_hash1}"), "http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-pam-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :translation_hash2}"), "http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-col-img-padding">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
      <%= link_to image_tag("footer-privacypolicy-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :privacy_head1}"), privacy_path %>
      <div class="footer-links">
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link1}", locale_root_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link3}", system_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link4}", manage_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link6}", clients_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link2}", about_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link5}", contact_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link7}", media_path %><br>
        <%= link_to "Facebook", "https://www.facebook.com/LightBeCorp", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "Twitter", "https://twitter.com/lightbecorp", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "LinkedIn", "http://www.linkedin.com/company/lightbe-corp", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link8} xxxxxxxxxx", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/bernarddreyer", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link8} xxxxxxxxxx", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/pamelacooktulsaok", target: '_blank' %><br>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link9}", privacy_path %>
        <%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :english}", locale: "en" %>
        <%= link_to_unless_current "Français", locale: "fr" %>
      </div>
      <p class="text-red-pad-top-10"><%= "#{t :footer2}" %> <span class="text-red">Light</span><span class="text-bluedark">Be</span> ©2010-<%= Time.now.strftime("%Y") %> - <%= "#{t :footer3}" %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Markup for header

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="row row-col-img-padding" id="pad-bottom-15">
    <p class="locale-line" align="center"><span class="english-link"><%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :english}", locale: "en" %></span><%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :french}", locale: "fr" %></p>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center" id="header-images">
      <div class="page-class" align="center">
        <ul>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag("menu-home.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :footer_link1}"), locale_root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag("menu-manage-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :footer_link4}"), manage_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag("menu-system-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :footer_link3}"), system_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag("menu-media-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :footer_link7}"), media_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag("menu-clients-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :footer_link6}"), clients_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag("menu-about-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :footer_link2}"), about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag("menu-contact-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :footer_link5}"), contact_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-col-img-padding" id="back-red">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
      <h1><%= @page_title %></h1>
      <% if params[:action] == "system" && I18n.locale.to_s == "fr" %>
      <% else %>
        <p><%= @page_abstract1 %></p>
        <p><%= @page_abstract2 %></p>
        <p><%= @page_abstract3 %></p>
        <p><%= @page_abstract4 %></p>
        <p><%= @page_abstract5 %></p>
      <% end %>
      <p><%= @page_abstract6 %></p>
      <% if params[:action] == "system" && I18n.locale.to_s == "fr" %>
      <% else %>
        <p><%= @page_abstract7 %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Ruby on Rails application.html.erb

```
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %> <!-- update app/views/layouts/_systemmessage.html.erb when you need to reboot the server -->
      <%= render 'layouts/systemmessage' %>
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/contact_footer' %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  </body>
```

The images below shows how my CSS works at widths 500px and 320px. The links and the images are using CSS .footer-links. They spread to the edge of the screen but the gradient does not.

[image]

[image]

CSS below

```
.footer-links { width: 1024px; padding-top: 10px; a { padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { body, footer, header, .box-message, .footer-links, .page-class, .red-line-1px { max-width: 100%; } }
```

Since the **header** and **footer** are within **body** I assume my problem is with the gradient width. I have seen many posts related to linear gradients and widths but I could not find anything that explained exactly how I need to change my CSS to get this working.

Comment: You need to provide the HTML as well, not just the CSS.

Comment: Please post a minimal code snippet of the rendered html/css, that actually produce the issue

Comment: Got curious, found your problem ... post the CSS for your `container-fluid` class and I will post an answer. Your `container-fluid` class has padding left/right 15px which cause the black margin on your footer, and why your header is not affected, is because it has a negative left/right margin that compensate for the padding.

Comment: I don't have any CSS for container-fluid. However the solid red line in my header works. Everything works 100% but the gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstraps `.container-fluid` rule looks like this

```
{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px}
```

So for your `footer` to work, you could do like this, where the major change is to add a wrapper `<div class="row">` and then remove the `row` class from 
`<div class="row-col-img-padding">`, and then set the gradient on the wrapper

Markup for `footer`

```
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row-col-img-padding">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-facebook-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "Facebook"), "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-twitter-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "Twitter"), "https://twitter.com/xxxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "LinkedIn"), "http://www.linkedin.com/company/xxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-bernard-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :translation_hash1}"), "http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-pam-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :translation_hash2}"), "http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-col-img-padding">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
          <%= link_to image_tag("footer-privacypolicy-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :privacy_head1}"), privacy_path %>
          <div class="footer-links">
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link1}", locale_root_path %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link3}", system_path %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link4}", manage_path %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link6}", clients_path %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link2}", about_path %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link5}", contact_path %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link7}", media_path %><br>
            <%= link_to "Facebook", "https://www.facebook.com/LightBeCorp", target: '_blank' %>
            <%= link_to "Twitter", "https://twitter.com/lightbecorp", target: '_blank' %>
            <%= link_to "LinkedIn", "http://www.linkedin.com/company/lightbe-corp", target: '_blank' %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link8} xxxxxxxxxx", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/bernarddreyer", target: '_blank' %>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link8} xxxxxxxxxx", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/pamelacooktulsaok", target: '_blank' %><br>
            <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link9}", privacy_path %>
            <%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :english}", locale: "en" %>
            <%= link_to_unless_current "Français", locale: "fr" %>
          </div>
          <p class="text-red-pad-top-10"><%= "#{t :footer2}" %> <span class="text-red">Light</span><span class="text-bluedark">Be</span> ©2010-<%= Time.now.strftime("%Y") %> - <%= "#{t :footer3}" %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Change your CSS `footer` rule to this

```
footer {
    padding-top: 0
}
```

Move content of existing `footer` rule to a new rule, `footer > .row`, like this

```
footer > .row {
    padding-top: 15px;     /*  added new property  */

    color: $gray; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 90%; line-height: 100%; a { color: $bluedark; } 
    background: red; 
    background: linear-gradient($red, $white);
    background: -khtml-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($red, $white); 
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. The gradient goes 100% at all widths. This is what I needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

You might not need both 100% on horizontal and vertical, but give it a try.

It is hard to see without your HTML. And you might need browser specific CSS also eg

```
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: I had tried background-size: 100%; for all the browsers I coded for but it did not work. I just tried background-size: 100% 100%; for all the browsers . It still does not work. I added my HTML in the question.

Comment: Well I am glad you got an answer which helped. It would have helped to know that you were using bootstrap. In these situations I usually use firebug to see what is causing the problem. Very often it is the container padding or something like that.

Comment: My CSS and markup had code it in that people I thought would have recognized as Bootstrap 3. I initially forgot to tag it as such but corrected that one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Copied your code, removed some css, and as I thought, the footer behaves as the block level element it is. Which means the margins on footer is due to something else than the code you provided, or it is in the code I took out of your css (although it shouldn't be).

And, if you had mentioned that you were using some sort of framework, and actually posted the CSS, not whatever non-built *CSS you have, this would have been easier. Also, had you made it into a fiddle, you would see that it is 100% wide. So, the problem is either because that footer is wrapped in something else (another div?), or because your example or code is not the actual code. Stop using framework-specific code in examples. At least when you don't mention what framework you're using.

```css
body { font-family: Arial; background-color: black; width: 100%; font-size: 18px; margin:0 auto; }

footer {
    color: gray; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 90%; line-height: 100%; 
    background: red; 
    background: linear-gradient(red, white);
    background: -khtml-linear-gradient(red, white); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, white); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(red, white); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red,white); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, white); 
}

#back-red { background-color: red; padding-bottom: 15px; }
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="row row-col-img-padding">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-facebook-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "Facebook"), "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-twitter-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "Twitter"), "https://twitter.com/xxxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "LinkedIn"), "http://www.linkedin.com/company/xxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-bernard-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :translation_hash1}"), "http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to image_tag("footer-linkedin-pam-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :translation_hash2}"), "http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx", target: '_blank' %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-col-img-padding">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
      <%= link_to image_tag("footer-privacypolicy-#{I18n.locale}.jpg", class: "img-responsive aspect", alt: "#{t :privacy_head1}"), privacy_path %>
      <div class="footer-links">
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link1}", locale_root_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link3}", system_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link4}", manage_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link6}", clients_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link2}", about_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link5}", contact_path %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link7}", media_path %><br>
        <%= link_to "Facebook", "https://www.facebook.com/LightBeCorp", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "Twitter", "https://twitter.com/lightbecorp", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "LinkedIn", "http://www.linkedin.com/company/lightbe-corp", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link8} xxxxxxxxxx", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/bernarddreyer", target: '_blank' %>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link8} xxxxxxxxxx", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/pamelacooktulsaok", target: '_blank' %><br>
        <%= link_to "#{t :footer_link9}", privacy_path %>
        <%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :english}", locale: "en" %>
        <%= link_to_unless_current "Français", locale: "fr" %>
      </div>
      <p class="text-red-pad-top-10"><%= "#{t :footer2}" %> <span class="text-red">Light</span><span class="text-bluedark">Be</span> ©2010-<%= Time.now.strftime("%Y") %> - <%= "#{t :footer3}" %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is the biggest comment I've seen so far ... and I can't see how it actually answers the question either. Please edit or delete

Comment: It does answer the question - does the code show a 100% width gradient? Yes or no?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, I was asked by you and another person to provide my CSS and HTML code and that's what I did, every single line copied straight from my web application. I'm using Ruby on Rails (which should not matter). I just added my header markup and a portion of the application.html.erb file that shows that my header and footer are in the same container-fluid div. As I stated my red line (id="back-red") in the header goes all the way across the line but my footer did not.

Comment: The code you add, and the tags you use tells us what to expect. That is not CSS, for one. The code inside the list tags in the html could have been removed, since it doesn't work if you don't run it off a server. You should know that this is not the smart way to ask a question.

Comment: First I read a big chunk of text that only complain about the OP's post, second, all I see is a big chunk of code, no explanation what so ever with what you did to solve the question, so it is pretty much useless as an answer, IMHO

Comment: So, an answer telling you the error is not in the code provided, is useless? But fine, I updated the answer

Comment: Well, an answer should answer the question, not tell that _the error is not in the code provided_, as that does **not** answer the question, it simply state that the error is elsewhere. So how does one give an answer when the error causing it is not present? ... does that make sense to you?

Comment: I have updated my question with a picture of what is happening. The problem is with the width of the gradient as everything else in my footer fills up to 100%.